# Is there a signed (ie anti-symmetric) version of SMAPE?

Tags: error, percentage, symmetry

The symmetric mean absolute percent error ([SMAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_mean_absolute_percentage_error)) is a symmetrized version of percent error with the formula:

$$\frac{200\%}{n}\sum_i\frac{|x_i - y_i|}{|x_i| + |y_i|}$$

SMAPE is symmetric: interchanging the $x$'s and $y$'s doesn't change the value. However, there are applications where it would be nice if an interchange of $x$ and $y$ changed the sign of the difference measure without changing the magnitude (ie if the measure was anti-symmetric).

For example, say that the value of an asset falls from $1 \rightarrow .95$, then recovers $.95 \rightarrow 1$. If you take the SMAPE of the price change events you get $5.13\%$. Instead I'd like to find an approach that would give an an answer of $0\%$ in this case.

#### Edit:

5 minutes after I wrote this question I thought of a simple answer (posted below). It would still be nice to know if there's an anti-symmetric percent difference measure that has actually been used before in the literature.

Comment: You are asking for a multiple of the "Relative Percent Difference."  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86708 for a generalization.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I think those are indeed the magic keywords

Answer (score 2):

I suppose one obvious way of getting an anti-SMAPE would be to just use the plain, non-absolute, difference in the numerator:

$$\textrm{ASMAPE} = \frac{200\%}{n}\sum_i\frac{x_i - y_i}{|x_i| + |y_i|}$$

Comment: Since sign cancels absolute value, both can be omitted.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You can also drop 200% since it doesn't make much sense anymore--it would be percentage of what?

Comment: @Tim the factor $200\% = 2\times 100\%$ doubles the ratio and converts that into a percent.  It does make sense.

Comment: The factor of $2$ comes from the fact that putting it in the denominator yields the average of the predictions and the actuals: $$ \frac{|x_i|+|y_i|}{2}. $$