# Is there multi-variate generalized MAPE(Mean Absolute Percentage Error)

Tags: regression, measurement, mape

The MAPE could be employed in the context of regression problem and is defined by
$$
MAPE := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^{n} \left| \frac{y_{t} - \hat{y}_{t}}{y_{t}} \right|
$$
where $y_{t}$ is target value and $\hat{y}_{t}$ is fitted value. In my intuition, it could be naturally generalized by
$$
gMAPE := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^{n} \frac{\left\| \mathbf{y}_{t} - \hat{\mathbf{y}}_{t} \right\|}{\left\| \mathbf{y}_{t} \right\|}
$$
where $\left\| \cdot \right\|$ is any norm of a vector, but I have noticed there isn't reference or any mention about it. Is it weird or wrong? I think $gMAPE$ is more reasonalbe and useful in many case compare to univariate target(Empirically, '$\mathbf{y}_{t}$ must be not zero-vector' a is easier condition than '$y_{t}$ must be not zero' is '$\mathbf{y}_{t}$ must be not zero-vector'), why nobody is interested it?

Comment: As much as MAPE has issues, it makes sense. Anyone with scientific acumen should understand that predictions tend to be within $10\%$ or $30\%$ of the true values. Even as a statistician, I struggle to have an interpretation of your proposed calculation, though you most certainly can calculate it for multivariate outcomes (if you really do have a multivariate outcome). I think I might prefer something like a double sum over the observations and the outcome variables, however.

Comment: @Dave Good point. Even  if we ignore the division, I find $\Vert y_t -\hat y_t \Vert $ not very intuitive. The minimizer would be some sort of multidimensional median...

Comment: @picky_porpoise With an $\ell_2$ norm, wouldn’t it be a multivariate mean?

Comment: @Dave Would be if the norm was squared, but like this its hard to interpret. But probably closer to the mean, yes

Comment: @picky_porpoise A monotonic transformation like a square root does not affect the minimizer. It seems like the norm and the squared norm should have the same minimizer.

Comment: @Dave The square root applies to the norm of each pair of forecast and observation individually, so it's not that easy. We can see this in the one dimensional case: The square root of the squared error is simply the absolute error, yet it is clear that mean squared error and mean absolute error are minimized by different statistics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar distances are used in literature since mid last century, e.g. so called [Canberra distance](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.patcog.2023.109646): $$\sum_t\frac{|y_t-\hat y_t|}{|y_t|+|\hat y_t|}$$

There are issues with Euclidian distances in high dimensions, of course. There's also a problem of units of measure and scales if the dimensions represent different features. So, as long as you understand limitations I don't see the reason to outright reject your distance metric.

If your data has a natural zero and all dimensions were of the same scale and UoM, then this should be quite reasonable. For instance, if we were providing a cartesian coordinate of a drone to shoot down $y_t$ and the actual cartesian coordinate of a projectile's explosion point $\hat y_t$, then your measure would give a reasonable measure of how close you got it in percentages. In this case if the center of the coordinate system is at the location of a gun, then we have a natural zero too.

Comment: Maybe it's called by sMAPE(symmetric mean absolute percentage error) also, at least in wikipedia. In your reference, I found the sentence "...it calculates the absolute difference between two vectors and normalizes it by dividing it by the absolute sum of their values. ...". It's what I wanted. Popular, famous, verificated and most important between two 'vectors'. Thank you so much.

Comment: In forecasting, this error measure (more specifically, twice it) is indeed known as a "symmetric MAPE" and has been discussed at least since [Goodwin & Lawton (1999, *IJF*)](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0169-2070(99)00007-2). I am amused that the ML community is once again reinventing a wheel. CV threads on the symmetric MAPE are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/507547/1352) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/145490/1352).

Comment: @StephanKolassa, ML community was using Canberra distance since at least 1967

Comment: @Aksakal: ah, thank you. I see I am hoist with my own petard...

Answer (score 7):

In principle and in theory, you can do this. However, I would definitely try to understand this error measure well before using it in any serious use case. I would recommend you take a look at [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352) for the univariate case.

The next step would be to simulate two-dimensional data and get a handle on what functional of this known distribution your gMAPE elicits. For instance, assume your conditional actuals look like this:

[image: simulations]

We can now run over a grid of possible two-dimensional forecasts and assess how well they would do to predict these simulates, as evaluated using the gMAPE:

[image: gMAPEs]

Now, it seems like the gMAPE is indeed minimized near the mean $\mu$ (per the link above, it probably won't be minimized by the exact mean), but it seems to have a very hard time understanding that other values on the top left-bottom right do not make sense. As a matter of fact, this looks so strange to me that I probably have a bug in my code somewhere... but I will leave this up as a possible way to investigate and understand the properties of the gMAPE.

R code (possibly buggy):

```
library(MASS)
library(hexbin)

mu <- c(6,6)
Sigma <- rbind(c(1,1),c(1,2))

n_sims <- 1e4
set.seed(1)
sims <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n_sims,mu,Sigma))
colnames(sims) <- c("x","y")
sims_matrix <- as.matrix(sims)
hexbinplot(y~x,sims)

fcsts <- as.matrix(expand.grid(x=seq(floor(min(sims$x)),ceiling(max(sims$y)),by=1),
    y=seq(floor(min(sims$y)),ceiling(max(sims$y)),by=1)))

fcsts <- cbind(fcsts,
    apply(fcsts,1,function(fcst)mean(sqrt(rowSums(sims_matrix-matrix(fcst,nrow=n_sims,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))^2)/sqrt(rowSums(sims_matrix^2)))))
colnames(fcsts)[3] <- "MAPE"

plot(fcsts[,1],fcsts[,2],type="n",xlab="x forecast",ylab="yforecast",main="gMAPE",las=1)
text(fcsts[,1],fcsts[,2],round(fcsts[,3],2))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, please take a look mine!