# What is the name for this metric?

Tags: regression, metric

I have been using the metric shown below for a while, in a power forecasting context. We call it `WAPE (Weighted Average Percentege Error`, but I have never seen any references in papers, just some questionable like [blogs](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/mape-vs-wape-vs-wmape):

$WAPE = 100 \cdot \frac{\sum_i |y_i - \hat{y_i}|}{\sum_i y_i}$

where $y_I$ defines de observed value and $\hat{y_i}$ the predicted one.

Is there any name for it? Exist any reliable publication or reference?

**EDIT**

Found an entry on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WMAPE) with this metric, named *Weighted Mean Absolute Percentage Error (wMAPE)*:

$$
wMAPE = \frac{\sum_i |y_i - \hat{y_i}|}{\sum_i y_i}
$$

Comment: Besides a weighted error you can also view this as 'the average error divided by the average value'. Thus computing some kind of average relative error by *first* averaging and then taking the reciprocals.

Answer (score 4):

**Some insight can be achieved by writing the WAPE explicitly as a weighted average.**

Recall that with any data $x_i$ and corresponding weights $\omega_i$ (not summing to zero) the weighted average of the data is

$$\operatorname{WA}(\mathbf x, \mathbf \omega) = \frac{1}{\sum_i \omega_i}\,\sum_{i}\omega_i x_i.$$

(When all the $\omega_i$ are equal and nonzero, this equals the usual arithmetic mean.)

Comparing to the WAPE suggests we let $$x_i = 100\, \frac{y_i - \hat y_i}{y_i}$$ be the *relative residuals* (in percent) of the data $y_i$ with respect to their predicted values $\hat y_i$ and let the weights be $$\omega_i = y_i.$$  Assuming all the $y_i$ are positive, so that all these ratios are defined and $|y_i|=y_i,$ we may rewrite the WAPE as

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{WAPE}(\mathbf x, \mathbf \omega) &= 100 \frac{\sum_i|y_i-\hat y_i|}{\sum_i y_i} = \frac{1}{\sum_i y_i}\,\sum_i  \left| 100\,  y_i \frac{y_i - \hat y_i}{y_i} \right| = \frac{1}{\sum_i \omega_i}\, \sum_i \omega_i \left|x_i\right|\\
&=\operatorname{WA}(|\mathbf x|, \mathbf \omega).
\end{aligned}$$

This reveals two things:

1. Yes, **the WAPE is a weighted average percent**: the percents are the absolute residuals $\left|y_i - \hat y_i\right|$ relative to the data $y_i$ and the weights are the $y_i.$
2. **This is a little strange,** because ordinarily one would express residuals relative to the *fitted* values, which would make the $\hat y_i$ the weights as well as the denominators of the $x_i.$

There are many reasons for (2).  For instance, most valid models of non-negative data will guarantee $\hat y_i \ne 0$ even when the observations $y_i$ might be zero or even negative (think of what an additive error term can do to a positive value).  As a result, it would be much more difficult to conduct a theoretical analysis of the statistical properties of your version of the WAPE in most situations.  I therefore doubt one can find many applications in the literature or even a standard name for it.

There are a huge number of ways to measure relative errors.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/201864/919 for a brief introductory account.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. The thing is, I'm forced to use that weird metric in a electric market forecasting context: the forecasts are evaluated using that formula

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not finding much because this statistic is not very interesting in general. First, what happens when $y_i$ are not all positive? The denominator can become very small (for normal $y_i$) or even zero (for discrete $y_i$). Even if $y_i$ are positive by the law of large numbers the denominator will be close to $n \mu$ where $\mu$ is the mean of $y_i$, so basically the metric will be approximately [mean absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation) divided by $\mu$.

Comment: Your final comment is incorrect: when the $y_i$ vary considerably, the result can be quite different from the mean absolute deviation.