# The best way to determine what percentile a range of numbers closely aligns with?

Tags: mean, quantiles

I have a table of ~600 numbers and percentiles like below:

| Data | 40th | 50th | 60th | 70th | 80th | 90th |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 71 | 53 | 55 | 57 | 60 | 63 | 68 |
| 101 | 78 | 81 | 83 | 88 | 92 | 102 |
| 121 | 89 | 94 | 98 | 105 | 110 | 123 |
| 209 | 146 | 153 | 163 | 171 | 176 | 189 |
| 68 | 71 | 74 | 77 | 81 | 85 | 92 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

What I want to know is what would be the best way to determine which percentile the 'Data' column falls closest to. On first glance, it looks to be the 90th percentile.

I calculated the percent difference between each Data number and each percentile in their own columns, then I took the average of each of those columns (only considering percent differences in the range -100% <= x <= 100%) to see which average percent difference was the smallest. I again think that the 90th percentile is what closest aligns since I ended up with 2% average % difference.

| 40th % Diff | 50th % Diff | 60th % Diff | 70th % Diff | 80th % Diff | 90th % Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -25% | -23% | -20% | -15% | -11% | -4% |
| -23% | -20% | -18% | -13% | -9% | 1% |
| -26% | -22% | -19% | -13% | -9% | 2% |
| -30% | -27% | -22% | -18% | -16% | -10% |
| 4% | 9% | 13% | 19% | 25% | 35% |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

| Percentile | Average % Diffs |
| --- | --- |
| 40th | -21% |
| 50th | -18% |
| 60th | -14% |
| 70th | -10% |
| 80th | -6% |
| 90th | 2% |

Or is my methodology off? Is there a better way of trying to determine which percentile is closest to the 'Data' column?

Comment: It all comes down to how you measure "closeness."  It could be the absolute difference, a relative difference, a difference in percentiles, and [many other possibilities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/201864/919).  Could you tell us what measure is suitable for your application?

Comment: @whuber Not entirely sure, was given this dataset and told to "determine which percentile the data column closely aligns with" and my first guess was to look at the differences between percentiles. Perhaps is there a way to calculate the exact percentile of the 'Data' column, like maybe it's actually the 89th or 91st percentile?

Comment: I suggest returning to your client for clarification about what they mean.