What kind of inter-rater-reliability metric to use for unbounded, real-valued data
I am analyzing the inter-rater-reliability of two annotators who annotated the monetary value (in USD) for a variety of products. To achieve this, they were task with finding said monetary value online per product. Therefore, the scale is real-valued and positively unbounded. Both annotators annotated all items. I came to the conclusion to use the Pearson correlation for this, but I am not entirely sure if this metric is applicable or whether there are any other, more applicable metrics. I have not been able to find a clear answer to this.

Of possible interest: Does Spearman's $r=0.38$ indicate agreement?

There's no general answer because a meaningful metric depends on the cost of inter-rater discrepancies in your application.  For instance, perhaps nobody would care if the two raters disagreed by 100% on items assessed by both to be near $1; or--at the other extreme--what matters would be relative agreement, which would be far more emphasis on even such low-price disagreements.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/201864/919 for a discussion of some of the issues in a similar setting of looking for an appropriate metric.

Pearson correlation involves auto-calibrating the values which means it doesn't measure accuracy.  In other words, one rater can be off by a factor of 2 and still have a correlation of 1.0 with another rater.  Instead I suggest concentrating on mean absolute discrepancies between (and possibly within) raters.  This approach is described in detail here.

Thank you for your response. I will read the link you included. Could you maybe elaborate further what you mean with the auto-calibration? Do you mean that if a rater is off by a factor of two over all items, the correlation is still 1? Because in that case, I would argue that that would not be likely in this scenario, where users search for the price of items online (I noticed that I described this part unclearly in the original question, so I edited that).

In general correlation coefficients are not fit for this purpose because they don't penalize for being off by a constant increment or by a constant factor (or both).

Well, the first thing to do, as with any data analysis, is to plot your data. Just run a scatter plot (and it would be great if you attached it to your question). A good plot is worth 1000 words? That should tell you all you needed to know about inter-rater agreement; after that, you just need to find a test/statistic which confirms what your eyes told you (this is called the IOTT, or "Inter Occular Traumatic Test", when the asnwer "hits you between the eyes".
Another plot you could use is a Bland-Altmann plot. It is just a "tweaked" scatter plot, and is designed specifically to assess agreement between 2 methods (in your case 2 raters) of assessing the same variable. Whether there is good enough agreement for your purpose, or not, should also hit you between the eyes.
Now, following the advice that "A little arithmetic to verify the extent of the trauma can yield great peace of mind for little cost.", let's see what arithmetic we can come up with.
The first, simplest thing to do is to do a t-test on the paired price differences. That will tell you if the 2 raters "agree", on average (if the CI of the mean difference includes 0, they do not disagree statistically significantly). But that is only "on average"; the observed mean could be 0, but with very large differences (cancelling each other out) on most items.  OK, but not very good.
The next thing to do is to do a linear regression of rater B against A, and of A against B. That will give you 2 slopes, and 2 intercepts; if both slopes are close to 1, and both intercepts are close to 0, then you have good agreement. Now do this only if the scatter plot showed good linear relationship, no wild outliers (regression is not robust to outliers), etc.
Note that there is a relationship between Pearson's r and the angle between the above 2 regression lines (see wiki). For good agreement, we want a small angle between the 2 regression lines. In the end, what you want is the 2 slopes close to 1, and hence Pearson's r also close to 1.
Note that Pearson's r by itself is not a good measure of agreement (it is a good measure of linear correlation, but correlation is not agreement). Say that rater B's prices are a linear function of rater A's ($B=\beta A + \alpha$), we would have $r=1$ (or -1 depending on the sign of $\beta$), but the slope would be $\beta$ (not 1), and the intercept would be $\alpha$ (not 0). But if you combine r with slopes=1 and intercepts=0, you now have confirmed the IOTT.
If the intercepts are not close to 0, there is an additive bias between the 2 raters; if the 2 slopes are not close to 1, there is a multiplicative bias between the 2 raters.
Last, you could use the MAE (Mean Absolute Error, since you have paired differences). The MAE will be expressed in \$'s, and you can directly assess if that mean is small enough for you to declare good agreement, for your purpose (is $MAE=\$1$ a good or bad agreement? depends on your context/application).
Or you could use the Mean Absolute Percent Error (MAPE). If there is a difference of \$5 on the price of a burger, that is a very large error; but if it is on the price of a new car, that is very small. So, depending on the range of prices you are considering, MAPE may be more appropriate as MAE.
